# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in - Erro PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma alteração no php, porém, está aparecendo um erro

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/canaljog/public_html/home/pages/principal.php on line 21
```

Conexão com o banco

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=canaljog_website", "canaljog_sa", "tcmm@0105");
```

O erro que está dando é na principal.php que é este

```
<?php 

                  $SQL_F = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE nome_categoria='slider'");

                  while($ft = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_F)){
                      $id_ft = $ft['id_categoria'];
                  }

                  $SQL_FN = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE categoria='$id_ft' ORDER BY id_noticia DESC LIMIT 1");
                  while($ftn = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_FN)){

                ?>


             <div class="item active">
              <a href="pages/noticia.php?id=<?php echo $ftn['id_noticia']; ?>">  


         <img src="adm/imagens/imgnoticia/<?php echo $ftn['imagem'];?>"  alt="<?php echo $ftn['titulo']; ?>" />

        </a>

<?php } ?>
```

O que pode ser errado ?

Comment: Está bem estranho esse código, a conexão é com PDO o erro é com o MySQLi e tem funções antigas (`mysql_*`) o erro diz que o primeiro argumento a ser passado para `mysqli_query()` deve ser a conexão.

Comment: Cara, seu código está muito errado! Você está misturando 3 tipos de conexão, o PDO, o Mysql (que nem existe mais nas versões recentes do php) e o Mysqli. Foque em apenas 1!

Comment: Ok. Eu vou fazer via mysqli. Já alterei a conexão. Conectou de boa, mas ainda continua dando o tal erro. Eu ja mudei todos o mysql para mysqli

Comment: Ja aprendi galera !! valeu pena ajuda !!!